# How to use .htaccess to rename or modify part of a query string

Tags: .htaccess

I need

```
http://somehost.com/?p=whatever&nothis=somevar
```

to go to

```
http://somehost.com/?p=whatever&this=somevar
```

Just trying to change the "nothis" part of the query to "this"!

Been banging my head and cannot figure it out!

I need a quick lesson here. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)nothis=somevar(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1this=somevar%2 [L]
```